# Chef: Use attribute in different cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm trying to use an attribute defined in one cookbook, say foo, in another cookbook,say bar. I get the error "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

```
Chef
    solo.rb
    cookbooks
        foo
            attributes
                default.rb
            recipes
                default.rb
            metadata.rb
        bar
            attributes
                default.rb
            recipes
                default.rb
            metadata.rb
    roles
        roles.json
```

Above is the structure of my chef.

**solo.rb**

```
cookbook_path File.expand_path("../chef/cookbooks", __FILE__)
json_attribs File.expand_path("../chef/roles/roles.json", __FILE__)
log_location STDOUT
log_level :debug
```

**roles.json**

```
{
    "run_list": ["recipe[foo::default]"]
}
```

**foo/attributes/default.rb**

```
default['foo']['var1'] = "Hello"
```

**bar/attributes/default.rb**

```
default['bar']['var1'] = node['foo']['var1']
```

**foo/metadata.rb**

```
name 'foo'
depends 'bar'
```

When I run the query `chef-solo -c solo.rb` I get the error as below

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in ../chef/cookbooks/bar/attributes/default.rb
================================================================================

NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
Recipe Compile Error in ../chef/cookbooks/bar/attributes/default.rb:
1>> default['bar']['var1'] = node['foo']['var1']
```

Here `foo` is my application and `bar` is [Chef Maven](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/maven). How do I import the attribute??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the cookbook dependency reversed. If you want to use the `node['foo']['var1']` attribute in the bar cookbook, then the bar cookbook should depend on the foo cookbook, and not the other way round.

Get rid of the `depends 'bar'` in **foo/metadata.rb** and create **bar/metadata.rb**

```
name 'bar'
depends 'foo'
```

Complete example:

```
|____cookbooks
| |____foo
| | |____attributes
| | | |____default.rb
| |____bar
| | |____recipes
| | | |____default.rb
| | |____attributes
| | | |____default.rb
| | |____metadata.rb
```

**cookbooks/foo/attributes/default.rb**

```
default['foo']['var1'] = "Hello"
```

**cookbooks/bar/attributes/default.rb**

```
default['bar']['var1'] = node['foo']['var1']
```

**cookbooks/bar/recipes/default.rb**

```
log "The value of ['bar']['var1'] is #{node['bar']['var1']}. The value of ['foo']['var1'] is also #{node['foo']['var1']}"
```

**cookbooks/bar/metadata.rb**

```
name 'bar'
depends 'foo'
```

**Sample output**

```
# chef-client -z -o 'recipe[bar]'    
...
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["bar"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - foo (0.0.0)
  - bar (0.0.0)
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: bar::default
  * log[The value of ['bar']['var1'] is Hello. The value of ['foo']['var1'] is also Hello] action write
```

Comment: "Foo" is my application, and "bar" is chef maven. I have a dependency of maven(bar) in "foo". Now I did try to add dependency even in bar about foo, but the error remained the same..

Comment: Can you create an example for us to look at? Either with real cookbooks or just foo and bar?

Comment: Added an example. To be honest I'm struggling to understand what you are trying to do. If you are using the Chef Maven cookbook, why are you modifying "maven/attributes/default.rb" and setting attribute values to attributes from your own application cookbook?